# Agents don't ring in queue (asterisk)

Tags: queue, asterisk, voip, freepbx, trixbox

I have a problem with my pbx. I'm using Trixbox and, as you can see from the log below, when a call passes from a queue, sometimes agents don't ring. Even if I restart amportal, the problem remains. I have to apply any change from the GUI (even without doing anything) to solve it.
Has anyone encountered the same problem? Or... does anyone know a way to monitor queues? So I can send an email when it happens.

```
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Goto (ext-queues,1000,1)
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [1000@ext-queues:1] Macro("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "user-callerid,") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:1] Set("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "AMPUSER=XXXXXXXXXX") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:2] GotoIf("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "0?report") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:3] ExecIf("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "1?Set(REALCALLERIDNUM=XXXXXXXXXX)") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:4] Set("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "AMPUSER=") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:5] Set("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "AMPUSERCIDNAME=") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:6] GotoIf("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "1?report") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Goto (macro-user-callerid,s,10)
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:10] GotoIf("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "0?continue") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:11] Set("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "__TTL=64") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:12] GotoIf("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "1?continue") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Goto (macro-user-callerid,s,19)
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:19] NoOp("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "Using CallerID "Test" <XXXXXXXXXX>") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [1000@ext-queues:2] Answer("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [1000@ext-queues:3] Set("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "__BLKVM_OVERRIDE=BLKVM/1000/SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [1000@ext-queues:4] Set("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "__BLKVM_BASE=1000") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [1000@ext-queues:5] Set("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "DB(BLKVM/1000/SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003)=TRUE") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [1000@ext-queues:6] ExecIf("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "1?Set(_DIAL_OPTIONS=TtrWwM(auto-blkvm))") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [1000@ext-queues:7] Set("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "__NODEST=1000") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [1000@ext-queues:8] Set("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "MONITOR_FILENAME=/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/q1000-20161102-123213-1478086323.3") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [1000@ext-queues:9] Set("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "__CWIGNORE=TRUE") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [1000@ext-queues:10] Queue("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "1000,t,,,10") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] DEBUG[6416] res_musiconhold.c: Music on Hold class 'one' not found in memory
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Started music on hold, class 'default', on SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003
[2016-11-02 12:32:13] WARNING[6416] mp3/interface.c: Junk at the beginning of frame 49443304
[2016-11-02 12:32:18] VERBOSE[6280] logger.c:   == Using SIP RTP TOS bits 184
[2016-11-02 12:32:18] VERBOSE[6280] logger.c:   == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
[2016-11-02 12:32:18] VERBOSE[6280] logger.c:   == Using SIP VRTP TOS bits 136
[2016-11-02 12:32:18] VERBOSE[6280] logger.c:   == Using SIP VRTP CoS mark 6
[2016-11-02 12:32:18] VERBOSE[6280] logger.c:   == Using UDPTL TOS bits 184
[2016-11-02 12:32:18] VERBOSE[6280] logger.c:   == Using UDPTL CoS mark 5
[2016-11-02 12:32:23] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Stopped music on hold on SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003
[2016-11-02 12:32:23] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [1000@ext-queues:11] DBdel("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "BLKVM/1000/SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:23] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- DBdel: family=BLKVM, key=1000/SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003
[2016-11-02 12:32:23] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [1000@ext-queues:12] Set("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "__NODEST=") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:23] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [1000@ext-queues:13] Set("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "__CWIGNORE=") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:23] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Executing [1000@ext-queues:14] Goto("SIP/XXXXXXXXXX-00000003", "ext-queues,1001,1") in new stack
[2016-11-02 12:32:23] VERBOSE[6416] logger.c:     -- Goto (ext-queues,1001,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved including

```
preload => pbx_config.so
preload => chan_local.so
```

in /etc/asterisk/modules.conf